# Is there any way to programmatically set the application name in Elmah?

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah

I need to change the app name based on what configuration I'm using in Visual Studio. For example, if I'm in Debug configuration, I want the app name to show as 'App_Debug' in the Application field in the Elmah_Error table. Does anyone have any experience with this? Or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Elmah uses the AppPool's application GUID as the default application name.  It uses this as the key to identify the errors in the Elmah_Error table when you look at the web interface that's created through it's HTTP Module.

I was tasked to explore this option for my company earlier this year.  I couldn't find a way to manipulate this by default since Elmah pulls the application name from `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId` in the ErrorLog.cs file.  You could manipulate it by whatever key you want; however, that is the AppPool's GUID.

With that said, I was able to manipulate the ErrorLog.cs file to turn Elmah into a callable framework instead of a handler based one and allow for me set the ApplicationName.  What I ended up doing was modifying ErrorLog.cs to include a property that allowed me to set the name as below:

```
public virtual string ApplicationName
{
    get 
    {
        if (_applicationName == null) {  _applicationName = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId; }
        return _applicationName;
    }
    set { _applicationName = value; }
}
```

What you will probably need to do is adjust this differently and set the ApplicationName not to `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId` but, instead, a value pulled from the web.config.  All in all, it's possible.  The way I did it enhanced the `ErrorLog.Log(ex)` method so I could use Elmah has a callable framework beyond web applications.  Looking back I wish I did the app/web.config approach instead.

One thing to keep in mind when changing the application name in Elmah.  The http handler that generates the /elmah/default.aspx interface will no longer work. I'm still trying to find time to circle back around to such; however, you may need to look into creating a custom interface when implementing.

Comment: Pretty minor quibble, but I like this pattern better: 
return _applicationName ?? (_applicationName = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId);

Comment: In the stored procedures in Elmah's database there are filters on application name.  I've changed all the stored procedures in my environment to ignore this filter so that I can view all errors in a single console.

Answer (score 53):

This can now be done purely in markup. Just add an `applicationName` attribute to the `errorLog` element in the `<elmah>` section of the web.config file. Example:

```
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" 
    connectionStringName="connectionString" applicationName="myApp"  />
```

I've tested this and it works both when logging an exception and when viewing the log via `Elmah.axd`.

In the case of the OP, one would imagine it can be set programatically too but I didn't test that. For me and I imagine for most scenarios the markup approach is sufficient.

Comment: Where exactly do you put this line of code? I can't get it to work. :(

Comment: In the <elmah> section of the web.config file.

Comment: Thanks. I just learned you have to define it in the `<configSections>` first.

Comment: It might be viable to use this in conjunction with Web.Config Transformation if different settings are needed by a `DEBUG` build. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35561167/397817 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx