# Elmah not all errors appear in the interface

Tags: elmah

Even though I have all the errors in MongoDb, I am not able to see them all in the list.
I am able though to access a specific error by ID (localhost/elmah.axd/detail?id=...)

The message on the top of the page "Errors 1 to 15 of total ..." is also correct.

The only thing I think may not be OK is that the time and date on the Mongo server is not the same with the one on the web server, and I see that web server's time and date are being displayed in the errors interface, and errors are also being sorter by this date and time.

I couldn't find anywhere anything on how does Elmah makes the Mongo queries in order to extract the list of errors and how does it transform the time in the DB in the time on the web server where it displays the data.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are multiple instances of the application writing to Elmah? Do you have for example a web app and an API app that write to it? Elmah will only display errors for a specific application, [you can specify the name in the web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329364/430634).

In the same question, a user makes a reference to how the default application name is determined, by using the appdomain GUID. That's another thing that could be different when multiple servers are involved.