# Application not using transform files of web.config while debugging with vs2012

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web.config-transform

is there a way to let Visual Studio run the web.staging.config or web.production.config while debugging (and not only after publishing)?

when i publish the solution the right config file (staging or production) is being used in the process and that is according the the publish settings i select. But when i try to debug the application in VS, it doesn't make any difference if select Staging or Production in the configuration manager.

how can i ask VS to use these files?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559289/web-config-not-transforming-when-debuging-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web.config is not transformed when debugging code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559289/web-config-is-not-transformed-when-debugging-code)