# Visual Studio not running correctly transformed config file

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, visual-studio-2017

My approach here may be wrong, so apologies if so - I'd appreciate any advice on what I did wrong.

I need to run (locally, for debugging), a specific configuration of a project that contains specific web.config transforms.

In my solution, in *Configuration Manager* I have the following listed:

- `Debug`
- `Release`
- `ClientFoo (copied from Release)`
- `ClientBar (copied from Release)`

I created a new entry, `ClientXYZ (copied from Debug)`, then right-clicked web.config and chose *Add Config Transform*.  I applied the transform rules, and when previewed, **the transforms display correctly**.

When I select ClientXYZ in the solution config drop down, and start the debugger...

[image]

...I see that the web.config used to initiate the application is the `Debug` one, and not my new `ClientXYZ` version.

Is it possible to run the project locally with web.config transforms applied, for debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web config transforms are only applied during publishing or building deployment packages by default (it does, after all, overwrite web.config).  There is a way with some adjustments, however, described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35561167/1464084

Comment: After reading this, I realise my question is actually a duplicate.  What is the purpose therefore of those dropdown lists in Visual Studio that I provided a screen grab of?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using "Debug" and "Release" in Visual Studio are:

- Debug constant defined in Debug configuration when you are developing application
- Release optimize code enabled in Release configuration when you host that application for client side testing or publishing
- Custom (`ClientXYZ`) constant defined for a developer's own settings (localhost or different IP's) for both Client site hosting and publishing your site

Comment: Yes, I realise this.  But the problem is that `ClientXYZ` does not get applied, so when the code runs locally, Debug/Release is always the *actual* code that's running, and not my *ClientXYZ* version

Comment: No, because I am trying to run the ClientXYZ build.